# IF statement containing four conditions but single answer (or blank)

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to get an IF statement containing four conditions to result in one answer (or blank).

Here is my formula:

```
=IF($L2=1,IF(AND($H2>=50,$O2>=5,$O2<8),"A: Priority 2",""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=IF($L2=1,IF(AND($H2>=50,$O2>=5,$O2<8),"A: Priority 2",""),"")
```